# ¿Como entiendo esta función?

Tags: javascript

Esta es la función:

```
function pedazos (array, cantidad) {
  var chunk = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += cantidad) {
    chunk.push(array.slice(i, i + cantidad));
  }
  return chunk;
};
```

La entiendo casi en su totalidad. Lo que no entiendo específicamente es esta parte:

```
chunk.push(array.slice(i, i + cantidad))
```

Por favor, alguien dígame que hace y porqué tiene las variables `i` e `i + cantidad`.

Comment: Empieza investigando que hace `slice` y pon todos los `console.log` que necesitas para ver como va cambiando la cosa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, debes entender la función de JavaScript [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Esta función devuelve una copia de una parte del arreglo dentro de un nuevo arreglo empezando por inicio hasta fin (fin no incluido). Con esto, sabemos que si tenemos un arreglo como este:

```
var nombres = ['Rita', 'Pedro', 'Miguel', 'Ana', 'Vanesa'];
```

E invocamos el método de esta forma:

```
var masculinos = nombres.slice(1, 3);
```

Nos devuelve lo siguiente:

```
['Pedro','Miguel']
```

---

Entendido lo anterior, pasemos a analizar un código de ejemplo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += cantidad)
{
    array.slice(i, i + cantidad)
}
```

Donde, asumimos que `array` es

```
['Rita', 'Pedro', 'Miguel', 'Ana', 'Vanesa']`
```

y `cantidad` es `2`. Esto equivaldría a lo siguiente en cada iteración:

```
// i es 0
// i + cantidad es 0 + 2 = 2
array.slice(i: 0, i + cantidad: 2) // [ 'Rita', 'Pedro' ]

// i += cantidad equivale a 0 += 2 que es 2
// i + cantidad es 2 + 2 = 4
array.slice(i: 2, i + cantidad: 4) // [ 'Miguel', 'Ana' ]

// i += cantidad equivale a 2 += 2 que es 4
// i + cantidad es 4 + 2 = 6
array.slice(i: 4, i + cantidad: 6) // [ 'Vanesa' ]

// En este punto, termina la iteración,
// pues nuestro arreglo es de 5 elementos e i vale 6.
// Entonces i > array.length y rompe el ciclo.
```

`chunk.push` va agregando cada pieza del arreglo de origen resultante de `slice` a tu arreglo llamado `chunk`.

Comment: gracias Hector M ahora entiendo como funciona eso a mas a profundidad!!!!

Comment: @esecorreo Si mi respuesta te fue de utilidad, puedes marcarla como aceptada empleando el check debajo del recuento de votos.